# Is there still a manufacturer building 10000rpm hard drives or higher?

Tags: hard-disk

I am unable to find one.
And below 2TB this doesn t gives advantages over ssd in size.

Comment: What research have you done?  Have you checked sites such as [PCPartPicker](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/internal-hard-drive/#t=10000,10025,10500,10520,15000) which let you filter?  I see they have a Seagate 2.4TB 10k (ST2400MM0129)

Comment: @AC this seems to be about used/refurbished hard drives. And according to seagate your model is a 7200rpm one.

Comment: If the "this" you refer to is PcPartPicker.com, then no, they're not about used items (though they might have listings for refurbs if the sites they scrape are listing those).  I _don't_, however, see very many options larger than 2TB.  I'm kinda surprised, actually, so +1 for the question as I'm interested in _why_ that's the case.  (And FWIW, according to this [datasheet](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/enterprise-performance-10k-hddDS1929-1C-1704US-en_US.pdf), that ST2400MM0129 is a 10k drive - I don't know, there may be a 7200 version as well)

Comment: Yes, the [WD VelociRaptor 1TB](http://products.wdc.com/library/SpecSheet/ENG/2879-701284.pdf), which is **currently rank 1 HDD** at the 1TB range according to https://hdd.userbenchmark.com/.

Comment: @AC yes. Espescially since higher data density allows higher throughoutput, which means a 20Tb hdd will always works faster than a 4Tb at 15000rpm.

Comment: @BennettYeo Velociraptor seems to no longer being sold by Western Digital.

Comment: @user2284570 It is sold at [Newegg](https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16822236245) and [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B007VPGJIY?tag=pcpapi-20&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1) assuming you can purchase from a US purveyor.

Comment: @BennettYeo I am not interested in a used model thanks.

Comment: I was not aware of that preference. Would this [New WD Velociraptor](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B007W715AI?tag=pcpapi-20&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1) from Amazon work for you?

Comment: @BennettYeo seriously, there s no longer a page on the official Western digital website detailing Velociraptor models outside datacheets which means the manufacturer is no longer producing them.

Comment: @user2284570, As the question is written right now, it's barely on topic since it's not explicitly asking for hardware recommendations, just whether the drives are still in production or not. We can infer that you are looking to buy one of these drives and want us to suggest models that are high RPM. Tell us your *other* requirements for the drive up front and you will get answers that are actually useful to you.

Comment: @Romen then it would be a duplicate of https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/12603

Comment: @user2284570, You've edited this question today but it's still **low quality** and arguably **off-topic** for this site because it is a simple **yes or no** format question. This question has already been raised by the community bot once before and I would like to either close this question or ask you to select an answer. The answers that have been provided are well beyond *complete* to answer the only question you have asked. The answer is **Yes**.

Answer (score 1):

There are only three companies that make hard drives these days; everyone else is just re-branding something produced by one of these three.  There's basically no market for high-performance hard drives these days -- even the fastest hard drive can't compete with an SSD -- and so nobody makes a 10k RPM consumer-level hard drive.  You've got only two options for a drive that's larger than 2 TB:

- A Seagate Exos 10E2400 2.4 TB hard drive, model ST2400MM0129, $350 or more.
- A Toshiba AL15SEB24EP 2.4 TB hard drive, $420 or more.

These are both enterprise-grade hard drives, in the 2.5" form factor (2.5" gives faster seek times than 3.5" at the cost of reduced throughput), with SAS interfaces.

I can't recommend either of them: at that price range, you can get an SSD with similar capacity and vastly superior performance, without needing to worry about finding an SAS adapter card for your system.

Comment: The same I m unable to find a 4Tb M.2 drive.

Comment: If you're looking for a 4TB M.2 drive, you've got one option: the [Sabrent Rocket](https://www.sabrent.com/product/SB-ROCKET-4TB/4tb-rocket-nvme-pcie-m-2-2280-internal-ssd-high-performance-solid-state-drive/#description), MSRP of $900.  It's about 12x faster than a hard drive for sequential reads, and 6000x faster for random reads.  If you're willing to relax your capacity requirements to 2 TB, you've got dozens of options; if you're willing to use a SATA interface, you've got about a dozen.

Comment: Is there an even larger M.2 drive?

Comment: Not right now.  As a general rule, if you want capacity, you buy a hard drive, if you want speed, you buy an SSD, and if you want both, you spend extra for a hybrid system that uses an SSD to cache the most-used parts of the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there still a manufacturer building 10000rpm hard drives or higher?

Yes.

There are still options available for enterprise customers, although most of these are drives that connect to SAS and are built into custom hot-swap enclosures. Many of them are less than 2TB capacity too.

Here are a few stores/links I could find with up-to-date information:

- [Dell](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/sas-hard-drives/ar/8351)
- [HPE](https://buy.hpe.com/us/en/options/drives-storage/server-hard-drives/server-hard-drives/hpe-server-enterprise-hard-drives/p/1009689640)
- [Lenovo](https://lenovopress.com/lp1059-lenovo-thinksystem-hdd-summary)

I am guessing that WD and Seagate no longer consider high RPM drives profitable in the consumer market against SSD storage; So they probably limited their production and sales of those drives to enterprise customers and entirely dropped the retail branding.

> And below 2TB this doesn t gives advantages over ssd.

There are SSDs currently available that saturate the bandwidth of SATA or SAS. Even a high density 15K RPM drive can't overcome that limitation, so I don't think high RPM drives have much of an advantage over SSDs at *any* capacity.

Comment: About ssd I was talking in terms of prices. And 7200rpm 20tb hdd are typically faster than those drives.

Comment: @user2284570, The only requirement that you specified in your question is that you're looking for hard drives with "10000rpm or higher", so maybe you should update your question if other things like price or actual performance matter to you.

Comment: Though I didn t see a 2TB ssd with a nand technology supportting more than 500 writes which is less than a DVD RW. Not even talking about nor based ssd.

Comment: @user2284570, I have commented twice now that your original question is lacking these requirements you have mentioned in comments. Please update it and I will revise my answer to address the changes to your question. I would like to remind you that **you have only asked one question**: *"Is there still a manufacturer building 10000rpm hard drives or higher?"*, and this answer addresses that specific question (**yes**). If you have more questions or requirements you *must* share them to get helpful answers. Or open a new question, since this one is *still* off-topic.

Comment: @user2284570, Where are you getting 500 from? The **warranty** on many 2TB SSDs may be void around `capacity * 500 TBW`, but that doesn't mean the endurance of the technology is limited to 500 program/erase cycles. I can find several TLC NAND chips that can theoretically handle 3000 to 10000 program/erase cycles. Making a 2TB drive in 2.5" form factor doesn't really imply that there are smaller, more delicate NAND chips either. There's a lot of room in a 2.5" drive for using the larger, more durable MLC or SLC NAND. You'll just have to pay more for it.

Comment: Simple my own experience with TLC contradicting manufacturer data. Also, there s no ssd with good quality mlc nand at that size. The largest slc drive is an Intel drive which is only 1.5Tb and worth more than $8000 supportting 116,000 4K write cycles (that price can be compared with the price of a 1Tb Velociraptor rated for 600,000 read and write cycles compatible with the same port).

Comment: If your real-world experience is that you kill most of your SSDs before they reach TBW, you are probably doing something wrong. What exactly would be a good question on Superuser.