# Single storage over 10Tb for 2.5inch sata or M.2 nvme

Tags: hard-disk, ssd, sata

In both cases/connectors, I don t care whether this is an hard drive or a ssd.
But the largest hard drive I saw for that case is 5Tb large whereas the largest ssd is 7.68tb large.

I want a single drive. Not as a raid array.

Answer (score 1):

That's gonna be either expensive or impossible.

I know of only one "m.2" NVMe SSD with more than 4TB storage capacity: Samsung PM983 15.3TB (MZ1LB15THMLA-00007). It costs more than 5000€ where I live, and is hardly available anywhere. Plus this drive is physically larger than a usual m.2 SSD (NGSFF form factor), so it might not fit into all motherboards/enclosures.
As for 2.5" SATA SSDs: they currently cap out at 8TB capacity. 2.5" SATA HDDs at 5TB capacity.

Comment: Thank you but where did you find the price reference? I don t even find a place where the price is quoted.

Comment: Only one shop I could find that has it currently listed: https://geizhals.eu/samsung-ssd-pm983-15-3tb-mz1lb15thmla-00007-a2175202.html?hloc=at&hloc=de&hloc=eu&hloc=pl&hloc=uk

Comment: What about U.2 drives since they are comparible with sata? I saw Intel has a 15.36tb ssd but It the largest thing I found.

Comment: Well, maybe...but probably no. You would have to double-check that the connector of the SSD physically fits to the connector in your laptop. And more importantly, that the drive is not too high for the hard drive bay in your laptop. Most laptops have room for 2.5" drives with 7mm height, all U.2 drives I found above 8TB are much thicker.